# google maps API getting lat and long values from DOM elements

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a google maps API project.

I take *lat* and *long* values from a database and display them in HTML rendered by PHP.

I want to draw a route on map when I click the button with the lat&long values. ( check the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFJuJ.jpg )

But there is something going wrong and always taking the same values to draw the route.

I try to use *changehandler* but does not work.

#### index.php:

```
<?php
    $test=mysql_query("SELECT lat, lng FROM markers  ");
    ?>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='row'>
        <center>
          <?php
          while ($deneme=mysql_fetch_assoc($test)) {
            extract($deneme);
            echo '<br>';
            echo '<h6 id="lat" class="box-design">'.$deneme['lat'].'</h6>';
            echo '<h6 id="lng" class="box-design">'.$deneme['lng'].'</h6>';
            echo '<br>';
            echo '<input id="submit" onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Button">';
            echo '</div>';
          }
          ?>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
```

#### JS:

```
function myFunction() {

    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ polylineOptions:{strokeColor:"#4a4a4a",strokeWeight:5}, suppressMarkers:true });

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
       pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
      infoWindow.open(map);
      map.setCenter(pos);

      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

      destLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById('lat').textContent, document.getElementById('lng').textContent);

      directionsService.route({
        origin: pos,
        destination: destLatLng,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
      }, function(response, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
          window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
      });

    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
    } else {
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Stop using the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: You can only have 1 `id` of a specific name on a page, so whats happening is you are breaking your DOM.  You can do this a bunch of different ways but the easiest for your implimentation would be to change your function to accept the lat/lng like `myFunction(lat, lng)`

Comment: Thanks for advice @AlexHowansky

Comment: It does not work actually, when i click buttons still route same way. @cmorrissey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like was mentioned in comments, the *id* attribute needs to be unique.

> <sub>The **id** [global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document.</sub> <sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)</sup>

Use a technique like the one below to add a numeric index to each set of latitude and longitude values with associated buttons. Notice the last reference (i.e. `onclick="myFunction('.$index++.')"`) uses the [post-increment operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) to increase the index for the next iteration of the *while* loop.

```
$index = 1;
while ($deneme=mysql_fetch_assoc($test)) {
    extract($deneme);
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<h6 id="lat'.$index.'" class="box-design">'.$deneme['lat'].'</h6>';
        echo '<h6 id="lng'.$index.'" class="box-design">'.$deneme['lng'].'</h6>';
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<input id="submit" onclick="myFunction('.$index++.')" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Button">';
        echo '</div>';
      }
```

Then since the javascript function *myFunction*() will now be passed an integer , that argument (e.g. named *index*) can be used to find the associated latitude and logitude values (or those could be used as arguments to in the function call instead).

So update the function definition to include that argument:

```
function myFunction() {
```

becomes:

```
function myFunction(index) {
```

and then this line:

```
 destLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById('lat').textContent, document.getElementById('lng').textContent);
```

can be updated to use that index:

```
destLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById('lat' + index).textContent, document.getElementById('lng' + index).textContent);
```

Also, to re-use the same directions service and directions renderer, declare those at the start of the javascript, and then initialize them in the function that initializes the map (e.g. *initMap()*):

```
var map, pointA, directionsService, directionsDisplay;
function initMap() {
    var options = {};
    /*
    code to setup options
    */
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), options);
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ /* ... */});
}
```

That way the code in *myFunction()* can just *directionsService.route()* and *directionsDisplay.setDirections()* when appropriate.

Putting all of this together, we have something like demonstrated in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/9z5c-k7uy).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id</sub>